# Which values does WebHost read from appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, self-hosting

In .Net Core you can self host a web server using `WebHost`. There is a method called `CreateDefaultBuilder()`, to which the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1) states the following:

> `CreateDefaultBuilder` performs the following tasks:
>
> - Loads app configuration from:
> - appsettings.json.

However, there doesn't seem to be any documentation on which parameters you can put into `appsettings.json` to have the `WebHost` automatically get configuration values other than the default values.

For example, I tried adding the following to my `appsettings.json`, but the server is started with `http://localhost:5000` regardless:

```
{
  "Kestrel" : {
    "urls" : "http://*:8080"
  },
  "server" : {
    "urls" : "http://*:8080"
  }
}
```

I know I can read `appsettings.json` myself using `ConfigurationBuilder`, but that sort of defeats the purpose of the documentation

So, what do I need to put into my `appsettings.json` file to have `CreateDefaultBuilder()` not use the default values? A list of all possible values to put into `appsettings.json` would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Why does CreateDefaultBuilder not configure the host with appsettings.json values?

Part of the answer is to distinguish between host and app configuration. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#set-up-a-host) says that `CreateDefaultBuilder`...

> - Loads **host** configuration from:
>
>   - Environment variables prefixed with ASPNETCORE_ ...
>   - Command-line arguments.
> - Loads **app** configuration from:
>
>   - appsettings.json.
>   - appsettings.{Environment}.json.

From within `CreateDefaultBuilder`, the reason that `appsettings.json` does not automatically affect the host, is that those settings are configuring the app, and the app config does not affect the host config. The documentation indicates that when it says:

> `IWebHostBuilder` configuration is added to the app's configuration, but the converse isn't true — `ConfigureAppConfiguration` doesn't affect the IWebHostBuilder configuration.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/67959ad853947d6ffef1916d02979753c0fd59e3/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L169-L170) shows that the `CreateDefaultBuilder` method only adds the `appsettings.json` values from within its call to `ConfigureAppConfiguration`. That is why those values are not automatically impacting the host.

#### How can we configure the host with values from a *.json file?

`CreateDefaultBuilder` does not automatically configure the host with a `*.json` file. We need to do that manually, and [the documentation specifies how](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#override-configuration). In the example the file is named `hostsettings.json`, and the example adds it explicitly like this:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json")
    .Build();

return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    // this impacts *both* host and app config
    .UseConfiguration(config) 
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

There is no magic in the name `hostsettings.json`. In fact, we could combine our host settings and our app settings into one file named `appsettings.json`. The way `CreateDefaultBuilder` works encourages us to keep those settings somewhat separate.

#### What keys can we put in a *.json file to configure the host?

This is the [list of keys](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/WebHostDefaults.cs) that we can use to configure the host:

```
"applicationName"
"startupAssembly"
"hostingStartupAssemblies"
"hostingStartupExcludeAssemblies"
"detailedErrors"
"environment"
"webroot"
"captureStartupErrors"
"urls"
"contentRoot"
"preferHostingUrls"
"preventHostingStartup"
"suppressStatusMessages"
"shutdownTimeoutSeconds"
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! I guess the difference between host and app configuration and lack of autoloading isn't obvious enough, and that I have to use `ConfigurationBuilder` after all (not that there's anything wrong with that).

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to hear the answer helped. :-)